# FusionPBX installation on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, installation, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-18.04, fusionpbx

Any way to breakdown this line of code? It always return permission error. I'm deploying fusionPBX on Google Cloud.

```
sudo wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fusionpbx/fusionpbx-install.sh/master/ubuntu/pre-install.sh | sh;
sudo cd /usr/src/fusionpbx-install.sh/ubuntu && ./install.sh
```

I got this error

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'fusionpbx-install.sh': Permission denied
sh: 13: cd: can't cd to /usr/src/fusionpbx-install.sh/ubuntu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your command:

```
$ sudo cd /usr/src/fusionpbx-install.sh/ubuntu && ./install.sh
```

only the left sided (first) command will run with root privileges:

```
sudo cd /usr/src/fusionpbx-install.sh/ubuntu
```

but the right sided (second)  command after `&&` will run with user privileges (`&&` means that the right sided (second) command will only run only if the left sided (first) command is successful):

```
./install.sh
```

you can see it in the error messages:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
```

or even more clear:

```
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

To make this issue more visible you can run this command:

```
$ sudo whoami && whoami
root
username
```

**To solve this issue** you should change your command:

```
$ sudo whoami && sudo whoami     
root
root
```

if you have a few commands that you need to execute you can do it in this way:

```
$ sudo -s
# whoami && whoami 
root
root
# whoami && whoami 
root
root
exit
$
```

In addition, I've checked [FusionPBX documentation](https://github.com/fusionpbx/fusionpbx-install.sh) and tried steps for Debian on my test VM:

> **Debian**
>
> Debian 9 is the preferred operating system by the FreeSWITCH
>   developers. It supports the latest video dependencies and should be
>   used if you want to do video mixing. Download Debian 9 Stretch at
>   https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/release/current/
>
> ```
> wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fusionpbx/fusionpbx-install.sh/master/debian/pre-install.sh | sh;
> cd /usr/src/fusionpbx-install.sh/debian && ./install.sh
> ```

but I changed them in compare to yours:

```
wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fusionpbx/fusionpbx-install.sh/master/ubuntu/pre-install.sh | sudo sh;
cd /usr/src/fusionpbx-install.sh/debian && sudo ./install.sh
```

and found no issues.